# Young adult novel about girl with purple eyes who gets sent to a magical boarding school

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

So I must have read this book around 10-15 years ago, but haven't been able to find any clues. It's driving me crazy.

It was a trilogy I think, maybe there could have been more books but I only read 2 of 3 books. The girl main character possibly had purple eyes, I only remember because the book cover was very white and then some violet eyes on it.

She was living with her grandma in the beginning who baked cookies a lot, her parents had died, she thought car crash but it was some magical stuff if I remember correctly and then she gets send to some magical boarding school where she lived with a girl that made pink sparks come from her fingers. There was something related to them getting powers from God's, maybe Greek and she was chosen by a Goddess.

Her powers are something related to touch, she could find people by touching objects I think and maybe also related to foresight. She had a male love interest, that had some troubled past. Last thing I remember is that they went on a skiing trip in the second book I think.

Please help

Comment: https://www.everand.com/book/414892411/Touch-of-Frost?

Answer (score 2):

This is [*Touch of Frost*](https://www.everand.com/book/414892411/Touch-of-Frost) (2011) by Jennifer Estep.

> My name is Gwen Frost, and I go to Mythos Academy—a school of myths, magic and warrior whiz kids, where even the lowliest geek knows how to chop off somebody's head with a sword. Logan Quinn, the hottest Spartan guy in school, also happens to be the deadliest.
>
> [image]

The (female) protagonist has violet eyes.

> "*Violet eyes are smiling eyes*", my mom had always said in a teasing voice. Her eyes had been the same color as mine, although I’d always thought they’d made her look beautiful and me just like a freak.

There's a fair bit of info about her cookie-baking granny

> Sorry,” I muttered, falling to my knees and attempting to scoop everything back into my bag before anyone got a good look at anything, especially the now-empty tin of chocolate-chip cookies that Grandma Frost had baked for me and the comic books that had slid out. The colorful pages flapped and fluttered like dragonflies in the breeze.

Her friend emits pink sparks

> Her French-manicured nails scraped across the white marble, and pale pink sparks of magic shot out of her fingertips. Daphne might only be seventeen like me, but Valkyries were incredibly strong.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much. I am pretty sure it is and the purple eyes were just something my mind made up

Comment: Violet is close enough to purple for most people, @Weslu. Also, if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow for every answer that's helpful, and the check mark for the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this seems to match the [Mythos Academy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?29874) series by Jennifer Estep; the first book, [*Touch of Frost*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1308813) was published in 2011, which puts it in your timeframe.  I can't find any English covers that match, but white covers with coloured eyes fits the German covers, at least according to [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18386402-halloween-frost).

[image: Cover of the German-language edition of "Halloween Frost"]

The other details seem to match, at least according to various reviews of the first book [on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9439989-touch-of-frost):

> Gwen has recently started attending Mythos Academy. **Her mom was killed by a drunk driver so now it is just her and her grandmother**. Gwen has a bit of gypsy magic which helps her find lost items for other students. She doesn’t have any real friends at school and often sneaks out of campus to visit with her grandmother.

> Gwen doesn't have any of the superpowers of her classmates (the Spartans' superpower, for example, is knowing exactly how to kill someone with any object that's lying around). Gwen's a Gypsy; her grandmother can predict the future, her mother knew when someone was lying, and Gwen's modest Gypsy gift is psychometry--**she experiences the thoughts, feelings, and memories (and hence the secrets) of anyone she touches skin to skin**, and that's something she avoids doing, partly so she won't freak out but also because it triggered the great tragedy of her life six months before.

Another review mentions her grandmother's cookies.

Comment: That's true, I read it in German which is why I probably remember that